# Combining MCMC with Variatonal Inference

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, variational-bayes, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I have a Gibbs sampler that is mixing terribly slowly. I have a hunch that if I sample a parameter pair as a single block, it would improve convergence.

I tried HMC within Gibbs, but it's also slow. I need many leapfrog steps to have a truly independent sample, about 10,000, and each leapfrog step takes about 5ms.

My next attempt is to use a mean field approximation to sample this parameter pair, and then plug it into my Gibbs sampler so I can sample the other parameters. If I have an analytic form for proposal distribution that maximizes the ELBO, it would significantly speed things up.

Is this approach sound, or should I simply sample all my parameters within the VI framework?
Is there another algorithm I can use so I can adequately sample the exact posterior? I've been reading on particle Gibbs, but I'm not sure how it can be helpful in my situation.

Here is the model I am sampling

$$
y_{it} = f(\eta_i, \lambda_t, \omega) 
$$

$$
\lambda_t = g(\lambda_{t-1}, \phi)
$$

where $y$ is observed. I wish to have a Gibbs sampler that samples $\eta$ and $\lambda$ together.

Although the SSM structure made me consider using a particle filter, it's not clear how I can sample $\eta$ within that framework.